# Android 4.0 ActionBar design-choice confusion

Tags: android, android-4.0-ice-cream-sandwich, android-actionbar

Recently I became the proud owner of an Android 4.0 tablet and have been snooping around trying to create some apps. Now that I have the basics covered, I'm diving more into the "what's good/what's wrong" parts.

As far as I understand, the old "menu/settings"-button is deprecated (in the sense that you shouldn't use it anymore) and now the ActionBar is the way to go. Upon reading further, I came across this: http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/ActionBarCompat/index.html

It shows how to use the ActionBar on pre-API 11 systems. On the left you can see the typical menu where all options are shown a developer decided weren't important enough to be in the actual UI (the "wrong" way, but programmed using the newer ActionBar API). On the right, that same menu is now on the ActionBar.

My question is: Since it's been said such an "overflow"-menu is bad design on older mobile devices, is it also bad design when it's on the ActionBar as a button like shown on the right screenshot? Or is it only considered bad design because on a lot of devices it required you to press a physical off-screen button which makes it a non-issue when it's a virtual button on the ActionBar?

In short: Should I avoid it or not? Frankly, I like the idea of having a menu on the far right with all options that either don't fit or aren't important enough to be their own entity on the ActionBar.

Please also point out if any of the information I gathered and explained here is wrong.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The options menu hasn't been removed, it's just moved. It used to be hidden "behind" the Menu button on the device, but it's now moved to the ActionBar. Items on the menu either show as icons on the ActionBar, or on the overflow menu. You use exactly the same code to add items, whether to the old style menu, or the new style ActionBar.

A big part of the improvement that's been made is there is now a visible button on the top-right of the screen to open the "menu" (ActionBar overflow), which is right next to the other options. this is much better than before where the menu button had no visual connection to the app.

I suggest you look at ActionBarSherlock, http://www.actionbarsherlock.com, as it makes it pretty easy to add the full ActionBar to pre Android v3.0 devices.

http://developer.android.com/design/patterns/actionbar.html

Finally, I'd suggest that you follow the UI guidelines from Google. If they say the ActionBar is the right approach for navigation, then use it. It's best to use the provided UI patterns, and focus on the domain-specific stuff in your app.

Comment: I love the design pattern website, wasn't aware of it, thanks!